# Помогите исправить ошибку 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
N = int(input(`Впишите количество чисел`))
ak = []
m = 1
for i in range(N):
      mas = int(input(`Впишите число`))
      ak.append(mas)
      m = i
      if mas[i] > mas[m+1]:
          print(`Да`)
      else:
        print(`Нет`)
```

Comment: mas[i] : тут mas - не список

Comment: опишите что должен делать ваш код

Comment: есть массив, содержащий N целых чисел, которые вводятся с
клавиатуры, и нужно выяснить, есть ли элементы массива упорядоченными по возрастанию

Comment: Назовут переменные как попало, а потом удивляются :)

Comment: Ну по факту так то и есть)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, что должно быть так:

```
N = int(input('Впишите количество чисел'))
mas = []
for i in range(N):
    mas.append(int(input('Впишите число')))
    if mas[i] > mas[i-1]:
        print('Да')
    else:
        print('Нет')
```